# Proper database design for this task

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Ok, so I am going to have at least 2 tables, possibly three.

The data is going to be as follows:

First, a list of search terms. These search terms are unrelated to anything else in the program (only involved in getting the outputs, no manipulation of this data at all), so I plan to store them separately in their own table.

Then things get trickier. I've got a list of words, and each word can be in multiple categories. So for example, if you have "sad", it could be under "angst" and "tragedy", just as "happy" could be under "joy" and "fulfillment".

Would it be better to set up a table where I've got three columns: a UID, a word, and a category, or would it be better to set up two tables: both with UIDs, one with the word, one with the category, and set them up as a foreign key?

The ultimate role is generating number of words in a given category over a given period of time.

I'll be using MySQL and Python (MySQLdb) if that helps anyone.

Comment: No offence, but I think you should have started with prototyping your queries, and not your data. How can you (and SO, if asked for help) design the database schema if you have only a vague (your 'ultimate role' statement) description of how you're going to use this database? What does 'over a given period of time' mean, for example?

Comment: not sure I agree. He seems to know what he wants, but maybe is not used to writing technical specs.

Comment: Using surrogate keys just slows this down - they are not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring your 'search terms' table (since it doesnt seem to have any relevance to the question), I would probably do it similar to this

```
words (w_id int, w_word varchar(50))

categories (c_id int, c_category)

wordcategories (wc_wordid int, wc_catid int)
```

Add foreign key constraints from the ids in wordcategories, onto word and categories tables

Answer (score 0):

Without having a whole lot of details, I would set it up the following way:

```
Word Table
id int PK
word varchar(20)

Category Table
id int PK
category varchar(20)

Word_Category Table
wordId int PK
categoryId int PK
```

The third would be the join table between the word and the category. This table would contain the foreign key constraints to the word and category tables.

Comment: downvoted the original question too. Some people *<rolls eyes>*

Comment: I did - just didn't bother repeating myself (not I who downvoted the question)